# How to ignore coveralls or any other user on github

Tags: github

I don't have anything against coveralls, but I don't want to be getting notifications from it, in the form of emails or having the notification button turn blue.

I examined [blocking a user](https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user), but that's not an option as I don't own the repo that coveralls is commenting on.

Is there anything I can do to ignore a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to:

- have a job monitoring every n minutes the notifications for a given project, and,
- if the last notification comes from a specific user, [mark those notifications as read](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/#mark-notifications-as-read-in-a-repository):

  ```
  PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/notifications
  ```

(In other words, there is no native "GitHub" solution, you have to write a service to get that particular feature)